# Is it possible to store the gravitational energy between planets somewhere in space?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, gravity, energy

Say I have a space station operating between Mars and earth. Can it somehow steal energy from

1. Mars- Earth
2. Earth - Sun
3. Sun - Mars
   Combinations of gravitational pulls?
   Would it distort he orbits?

Comment: I'm not sure at all what you want to do.  What do you mean by "*stealing the gravitational energy between planets*"? Without going into general relativity's theory, planets exert gravitational forces (not energy) onto one another. This force is not some sort of invisible rope you can physically touch, that's why I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: @Tortliena in classical newtonian physics,  the gravitational potential energy of a system is a well-defined quantity. If you insist on making GR threats, the metric tensor replaces it in that framework, but then again your claim that gravity is a force indicates that you indeed are not considering a relativistic framework. OP is asking if there is a way to harvest that potential energy and convert it into usable energy (presumably in a way that does not destroy the solar system)

Comment: @BarbaudJulien even then, all GR will tell you is "lmao no". Maybe you could argue something akin to the Penrose process might work. Guess the core problem is you will never get more energy out than you put in. As in, you can for instance use a stationary weight to i guess slow an orbit down, but you will just expand as much energy as the system loses.

Comment: @ErikHall as both tortliena and I mentionned, neither of our comments is adressing a relativistic framework. I also virulently disagree with your idea that GR prohibits energy extraction from a gravitational system. I disagree with even more virulence with the idea that, were GR to type, it would use "lmao" to answer people. I might post an answer which will (of course) not talk about GR

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Yes. On the GR stuff, my point was that you will probably not get any energy gain. Even the Penrose process is a rather idealized framework that really dosnt work in practice. Even in simulations it is pretty hard to get working. So my assumption is any body system mising an Ergo sphere wont be easier. If we leave aside gravity assists i guess

Comment: @ErikHall OP is not asking for energy gains, he is asking for a way to tap into a source of potential energy, which is conceptually reasonable (tho practically a bad idea). I will post a proposed process to do so. The Penrose process also doesn't have much to do with the question

Comment: I am aware, but if your goal is to get Energy presumably you want more energy out than you put in no ? Penrose does, because it is a way to extract rotational energy, which really the angular momentum of an orbit is in that respect the same. My point is that this is not easy. But ill watch out for your answer.

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Thanks for the clarification . What's still left is whether the querent wants something akin to a reliable, constant power plant or something more to be used once (e.g. : Sattelites using the gravity to sling themselves at high speeds ➡️ L.Dutch's answer).

Comment: @Tortliena true, the question is a bit shaky. But his use of the word "store" energy to me suggests more of a constant power source

Comment: Your better off with solar panels, completely known and understood technology.  As far as storage of gravity its called a blackhole, however there is basically no safe way to have one so close.  Maybe if it was limited to a few millimeters, but once if it expands you have BIG problem.

Comment: @cybernard any bodies orbiting each other are storing potential gravitational energy. You don't need black holes to store gravity. It's not because people think they sound cool that you have to bring them up every damn time someone talks about space

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, the question is formulated a little bit loosely, so let's try to understand the implications of what you are asking. I will focus solely on extracting gravitational potential energy from the sun-earth system because you can't ask 3 questions in one, and other planets than Earth bore me to death. We will work under the assumption that the mass of the sun is so great that it is a fixed point, and earth is orbiting in an ellipse around it. We will use newtonian physics because using anything else would be as pedantic as useless for our purposes.

### How do we extract gravitational energy? - We make the earth fall

What your question as formulated is asking, is a way to extract potential gravitational energy from a 2-body system. It's conceptually very straightforward. Gravitational energy decreases as the bodies get closer. So what you want is a way to get the earth closer to the sun.

In other words, you want to make the earth *fall towards the sun*. This will convert its gravitational energy into kinetic energy (the earth will gain some speed as it falls), which you can try and find a way to harvest (slowing down the earth to steal its energy). This makes intuitive sense. This is very much what we do on Earth with hydropower: we let some water fall to accelerate it and we steal some of its movement energy on the way with big wheels. You are proposing to do the same thing, but using the earth as the water

### OK. how do we make the earth fall? - We slow it down

Cool. How do we make the earth closer to the sun? Well, simple, we slow it down. You can essentially see an orbit as the equilibrium between a centrifugal  "force" and the attractive gravitation force. If you slow the earth down, the centrifugal force gets weaker. And the gravitation starts winning. So it pulls the earth closer, accelerating it on its way, until centrifugal force gets strong enough that you reach another equilibrium on a tighter orbit.

So you see the idea, conceptually: we find a way to slow down the earth (extracting its energy of motion). Then the earth starts falling a bit, which accelerates it, providing you with more speed to steal, making it fall, etc, etc.. You're essentially stealing the speed of the earth, which gravity constantly replenishes (until you crash into the sun)

### Ok. But how do we steal Earth's speed? - Magsails (maybe)

Alright, that's the tricky part. Obviously, there's no practical technology within reach that could do that. You could slow it down *actively* (e.g. by using huge rockets that push against its motion), but that requires you to spend energy, clearly dumb.

A nice way that we would love to be able to do, would be to build some sort of giant windmill protruding from earth (let's ignore the fact that no material would be strong enough to build it). If there was air in space, the windmill wooshing through it would start turning like crazy, providing energy and slowing down the earth because of the drag induced. That would be our perfect way to slow down the earth by stealing its kinetic energy. But there's no air in space.

No, but there's other stuff. In particular, there's some sort of wind; solar winds. Magnetic particles farted out by the sun, that you could use to propel yourself with a [magnetic sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_sail). Then, the concept of the windmill gets a second life! Just build the blades of the giant planetary windmill as enormous magnetic sails. If it is possible to have those things oriented so the sails always oppose the movement of the earth (I don't know that), then hurray! You found your way to use drag to activate your windmill. It's not air drag as usual, it's magnetic drga but it's the same idea and slows down the earth to make it fall. You did it, you're stealing from the gravitational energy of the system, you bad boy.

### OK but is it practical?

Hell no. But the windmill idea is very naive after all. Who knows, maybe some craftier engineer could come up with a more practical way to slow down the earth.

### Ok but if we said it was practical anyway, would it be a good idea?

[this section, while true in principle, will be corrected below]
Hell no. Even from a purely conceptual point of view. Again, the only way to extract gravitational energy is to fuck with the orbit and make your planet get closer to the sun. That is probably never gonna be a good idea.

### Erratum: you can actually extract plenty of energy without much consequence

Thanks to @NuclearHoagie for pointing this out. Let's do a tiny bit of math.

How much energy can we extract from the system without significantly fucking things up? Well, let's say we slow down the earth by $\Delta v = 1m/s$ (it's not much, the earth goes a really fast)

The energy we get from that is readily obtained as:
$$\Delta E = m/2(v^2-(v-\Delta v)^2)$$
If we assume that $\Delta v << v$, we can linearize and simplify that to:
$$\Delta E \approxeq mv\Delta v$$
Since the mass $m$ of the earth is so large, that means lots of energy. Like a lot, a looot. Plugging in the right numbers, we get about 5e13 TWh of energy. That's nuts. Currently, the world consumes about 25 000TWh/year

**Reducing the speed of the earth by 1m/s would give enough energy to power the current world energy needs for 2 billion years**

Granted, your civilization is doing crazy shit and is likely to need dozens of times more energy than we currently do, but still. Granted, your process is not gonna be 100% efficient, but still.

How much impact would 1m/s have on the orbit? Peanuts.
We just calculated the energy taken away from the system. If we assume a circular orbit for simplicity (not far from true), there is a simple formula telling you how close to the sun you orbit for a given specific orbital energy $\epsilon$ (energy per mass):
$$r = -\frac{\mu}{2\epsilon}$$
where $\mu$ is something involving the mass of the sun and some constants, nevermind.
That means:
$$\Delta r = -\frac{\mu}{2(\epsilon+\Delta \epsilon)} + \frac{\mu}{2\epsilon} = -\frac{\mu}{2\epsilon} (\frac{1}{1+\Delta \epsilon / \epsilon} - 1) $$

Assuming $\Delta \epsilon << \epsilon$ and making proper linearizations, we simplify that to:
$$\Delta r \approxeq \mu \frac{\Delta \epsilon}{2 \epsilon ^2}$$
Finally, using $\Delta \epsilon=v\Delta v$ as calculated previously, and the circular orbit formula $\epsilon = -v^2/2$, we get:
$$\Delta r = 2\mu \frac{\Delta v}{v ^3}$$

Plugging the right speed numbers in there, we get $\Delta r = 10 000km$. This is nothing at all. The eccentricity of the earth's orbit means that its distance to the sun actually varies by about 5 million km from periehlion to aphelion. A mere 0.2% of that is not gonna have severe impacts on the planet.

**Conclusion: you could get energy for your civilization for 2 billion years (or at the very least millions of years even with pessimistic assumptions), for no significant impact on your orbit.**

That doesn't change the fact that, practically speaking, this remains insane. But theoretically it is a bit more appealing. Another thing that I didn't mention is that it would be hard to induce some drag to slow the earth's orbit without affecting its self-rotation as well. Your day/night cycle is probably gonna be impacted too; I didn't do the maths on that one, but the impact is probably going to be negligible too

Comment: Doesn't this describe how planetary slingshots work?

Comment: Pfft, that's future humanity's problem. Who cares about those losers? /s

Comment: @hitchhiker not really, a slingshot will only steal some energy from the system once as it passes by the massive body. It also doesn't seem like a practical way to harvest that energy and convert it into usable work (i.e. electricity). The process proposed here, if at all feasible for their fictional level of technology, could harvest energy continuously until the orbit collapses into the gravitational center. But there are some similarities indeed in the sense that planetary slingshots do steal from the gravitional energy of the system as well

Comment: Changing the earth's orbital speed by just 1m/s (0.003% of its orbital speed) would provide enough energy to meet current worldwide demand for a million years. You of course can't do it forever, but there is a *lot* of energy to be had with rather small changes to the orbit - maybe not such a terrible idea as it first seems.

Comment: gravity assists are a way to slow down a planet, but I'm not sure that answers how to store the energy, as all you get is a faster thing, but not necessarily on a convenient orbit, and no way of directly converting that energy into something useful

Comment: @njzk2 as already mentioned to hithchiker, this answer is not about gravity assists

Comment: @NuclearHoagie According to some quick calculations, 1m/s would actually meet the current world annual energy demand for 2 billion years (and 1m/s is 0.3% of orbital speed btw). Damn. And it would only get the earth closer to the sun by 10 000km, aka almost nothing. That's a good point, I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Doesn't change the fact that the solution is very impractical, but philosopically it is a bit more ok

Answer (score 3):

Physics is all about transforming one form of energy in another form of energy. That said, if you let something that is orbiting a planet go orbit in a lower orbit, it will lose some energy that must go to somewhere else and hopefully that somewhere else is where you harvest it to perform useful work.

In order to change the movement of something (like a planet in orbit), we need to rely into Newton movement laws, and the 3rd says that for every action there is a reaction that is equal and opposite. So, if you want to exert a force into a planet, you will need to apply a force in the opposite direction. By the 2nd law, force is the product of mass and acceleration, which means that you should throw out some mass. The most efficient known way to throw out mass with vigorous force is by exploding a fuel that creates huge quantities of force into one direction and transfer part of the explosion force to the body that you want to propel in the opposite direction. This is what a rocket engine does and even what a hypothetical nuclear rocket engine would do. You could even improve on it if you could also somehow harvest the enormous quantity of light and heat produced in this reaction. But this doesn't have anything to do with gravity afterall and also means that you would be spending massive fuel that would eventually be depleted.

An orbiting object is continuously swapping kinetic energy to potential energy back and forth. If you harvest potential energy, it goes to a lower orbit. If you harvest kinetic energy, it will have less momentum to trade back to potential energy and also goes to a lower orbit. So, unless there is some other process replenishing that energy or it is so abundant that it would take billions of years to deplete (i.e. getting so low that the orbiter crash down into the orbited body), this wouldn't work or would be very short-lived. Luckily, planets in the Solar System, would take trillions of years to crash down into the Sun by any reasonably thinkable mean to harvest their orbiting energy. And in fact, in roughly five billions of years, the Sun will turn into a red giant and end that party much earlier, so you can surely harvest that energy in some way without having to bother about replenishing it.

Directly harvesting gravitational binding energy (i.e., what glues matter together so it becomes a planet) is very hard. Part of the reason for that is because negative gravity doesn't exist as far as we know, unlike what we see in electromagnetism and also there isn't any know way to conduct or isolate gravity as we do with electricity, this means that you will need to rely in very indirect ways. Also, once stuff is glued down together by gravity, have part of it becoming potential energy again means having part of it separated and put at some distance of the rest, which won't happen if you don't use some energy. So, this is also likely a no-go. But this isn't orbiting energy either.

So, the best that we usually do in order to use gravity to perform work is to let something fall down to the ground hitting it with some force and harvesting the energy of the impact or simply having something rolling downhill and collect its kinetic energy as it gains velocity and produces force. And then, either have a renewable source of things falling down (as in hydropower) and/or relying in some other process that would make things that went down go back to up and restart the cycle (like the sun heating up the oceans and producing clouds which rain down). But none of this seems to work in your scenario.

My advice would be to forget it. Surely there are some ways to harvest gravitational energy from planetary orbits, but they are so inneficient, wasteful and low-yielding, that any much more mundane way to harvest energy would likely be much more useful and practical.

Comment: gravitational binding energy is not what you think it is. It is what holds a planet together

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Well, that was exactly what I mean to say. However, I will review this post if that didn't became clear enough.

Comment: Oh ok, I probably misunderstood that part. This is not what OP is asking tho (binding energy is what makes a planet keep its integral shape as a semi-sphere, instead of just being independent rocks. Are you sure that is what you meant?)

Comment: Other than that, I am mostly in agreement with your answer, but I do propose in my answer (posted at the same time as yours) a process to harvest the kinetic energy of the planet. It is practically ridiculous (especially in terms of materials) but conceptually sensible as far as I can tell. You can check it out in my answer, I'd be glad to get your thoughts

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Well, the question is very loose, so I tried to cover all the bases, and perhaps that was a base that I didn't need to cover at all. Anyway, I read your answer and upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

We are stealing the kinetic energy of the earth's moon -- that's what tidal power generation is.

By taking energy out of the tidal flow, the water is held back, which gives a slight offset to the center of gravity of the water on earth, and this slows down the moon's orbit.

Comment: I considered this too but I don't think this answers the question as formulated. OP is explicitly asking for a way to steal the gravitational energy of some specific 2-body celestial systems ({sun+earth}, {mars+sun}, or {mars+earth}). Tidal power generation uses the gravitational energy of the {moon+ocean} system, not the gravitation between two celestial bodies (i.e not even {moon+earth} system, which would still not be an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Anything orbiting a planet stores gravitational energy, in form of potential energy.

With a swing-by it is possible to steal energy from an orbiting body, but usually the impact on its orbit is negligible.

Comment: It's only negligable if you fail to do it in sufficient scale! =)

Answer (score 0):

Orbital energy is akin to potential energy.

To extract it you have to move the body.

With a weight in a high place you can use some electromechanical device to convert the potential energy to some other form of energy; for example you could use a rope and lower the mass while driving a generator.

With orbiting bodies this is a bit more difficult for several reasons:

- as others already pointed out stealing orbital energy essentially means to slow down the planet and thus making it rotate nearer to the Sun; this may or may not be desirable.
- due to momentum conservation laws you cannot just slow down anything (and "anything" includes planets, of course) without transferring (part of) its momentum to something else. This is the reason why manouvering in space needs "reaction mass" ( using a rope between planets is a bit impractical).

There actually ARE means to extract orbital energy from a planet, but are rather involved: you need to have a mass (or a series of masses, of course) doing close orbit BEHIND the planet and then be accelerated while slowing it down ( planet is much more massive, so it's slowdown is not noticeable) you then have to extract kinetic energy from the mass and send it again to get more energy from planet.

A good exercise would be to use Jupiter and some of its trojans (which would be somewhat accelerated) capturing some of the mass kinetic energy on each pass, probably using electromagnetic coupling.

In any case you need (at least) two BIG masses and some kind of "rope" to steer them.
Not exactly the easiest way to get energy, even with current shortage.

Comment: I had to stop reading after "Orbital energy is akin to potential energy." which, to paraphrase Pauli, *is not even wrong*

Answer (score 0):

*(**WARNING:** The following is **not science.** You asked for it with that `science-fiction` tag boyo.)*

The "rubber sheet" model is a handy - if only mildly useful - analogy to what's happening. And while it's wildly inaccurate in its depiction of how gravity actually functions (since it uses additional dimensions and *actual gravity*), it does serve as an illustration of something interesting: deformations in spacetime.

Take a rubber sheet with a fine grid on it, stretch it on a frame and place a bowling ball in the middle of the sheet. Gently. (*We do not throw the bowling ball, do we Peter?*) The sheet deforms, and the more deformed it gets the larger the area of the little grid cells gets. This is due to the stress placed on the rubber sheet... which is a neat little analogy to the stress placed on space-time.

It's that stress that we're interested in, since it does so much of the work for those gravity effects. Yes I know, geodesics through curved spacetime do most of it, but that's only part of the picture isn't it. It doesn't explain frame dragging for one thing.

Fortunately, stressed space-time is a wonderful place to store energy if you don't mind a few interesting side effects, like the time I lost a rather nice stylus during a power surge. Or how we still can't find the back end of Gary's cat... which admittedly has led to a non-zero saving in kitty litter around the lab.

But I digress. (Frequently.)

Storing energy is of course the opposite of what you're after, but what can be stored can always be retrieved. Or something like that. Ignoring entropy. And black holes. (*Yes, thank you again for that, Peter. You still owe me a replacement lunchbox.*) All it takes is gradient to allow that stress to release in a way we can exploit.

Now normally we'd stress space using powerful electro-static fields between very narrowly separated metal plates, with a very high-strength insulator in place to prevent the electrical charges from neutralizing. Clearly that's not what you're after here. You want something with a bit more zing, am I right?

Here, let me show you what Carl has been doing with wormholes. Kid's a bit of a savant, if you know what I mean. Can't even tie his own shoelaces, but boy can he punch holes in reality. Once we got him to stop taking things out of the wormholes before they ever went in the other side - try not to think about that, it hurts - we had him building short separation ERBs with zero internal depth. As soon as something enters it's already leaving.

Which, as Peter found out the hard way is a fabulous way to get a medium dose of xray radiation while losing half a finger. (*Yes Peter, we know it was the little finger, not the hole finger. And that's still not funny.* If he weren't the director's kid...) Turns out that the difference in space-time tension on either side of the hole equalizes a tiny bit when you send something through. If they're approximately equal then nothing happens. The larger the difference... the more energy is released into the object as kinetic energy relative to the non-existent frame of the "inside" of the wormhole. And when some idiot decides to see if he can replicate "Portal physics" in real life and stray particles start accelerating to a sizeable fraction of the speed of light... well, you don't stick your finger in the middle of the light show is all I'm saying.

On the plus side all that energy we take out is almost immediately replenished. We've yet to notice any actual change in the various measurements, even if Allison is convinced that we're going to alter the Higgs field or provoke a false vaccuum collapse or something if we keep tinkering with it. We're all still here though, so I'm taking it on faith that she dropped a decimal somewhere. (First times come for everyone Alison, just deal with it.)

So... wrap a bit of spacetime up into a tube, shrink the internal dimensions a little and pull the real-space interfaces out into regions of different gravitational stress. Throw some junk in one side, collect the junk - and a bunch of very energetic photons - out the other. Profit.

Just... maybe get someone to go over the numbers with Allison first. I'd really *really* like to find the mistake before we put this baby into production.